# Are $\Bbb R^2\setminus \Bbb Q^2$ and $\Bbb R^2\setminus \Bbb Q^2\cup \{(0,0)\}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

As the title says I was wondering (being vaguely inspired by a question from Hatcher asking about the fundamental group of the first space) whether $\Bbb R^2\setminus \Bbb Q^2$ and $\Bbb R^2\setminus \Bbb Q^2\cup \{(0,0)\}$ are homeomorphic.

My gut feeling is that they are, they have the same properties as far as connectedness, compactness and separation axioms are concerned, supporting this feeling, but I haven't been able to prove (or disprove) this fact.

Comment: I have the vague inkling that it will be easier to consider the one-point compactifications, i.e. $(\Bbb R^2 \cup \{\infty\}) \setminus \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @ThePortakal $(t,\sqrt{2}t)$ with $t \in [0,1]$ is a path connecting $(0,0)$ to $(1,\sqrt{2})$ which doesn't leave the space in question.  Remember that a point is in the space if at least one of its coordinates is irrational.

Comment: Nice question. I just spent about an hour trying to construct a contradiction by extending the map to an automorphism over $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then subtracting a suitable set, using uncountability of the irrationals. However, either I forgot the contradiction, or I was hallucinating mathematically... I guess it was the latter :(

Comment: @polynomial_donut I would love to see a proof that you can extend it to an automorphisk of R^2.

Comment: @MikeMiller 'automorphism' as in 'automorphism in the category of topological spaces'? Might be nonsense, but here goes a short version, assuming a homeomorphism $f$ as in question: Enumerate the rationals. For the first, say $q$, pick a sequence $(s_n)_n$ in the codom with limit $q$ (when included in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Define $F(q)$ to be the limit of $(f(s_n))_n$. *Should* independent of the particular choice, because the spaces are T2. Define an extension of $\phi$ to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{(0,0),\;F(q)\}$. Proceed inductively to obtain a continuous map(?)

Comment: There's no reason to think that $f(s_n)$ should converge.

Comment: Take a look at theorem 7 in http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00013058.pdf

Comment: @MikeMiller Shouldn't it work by continuity in both senses?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Sure, if it extends continuously to all of R^2 (when we extend the codomain). I don't know why that should be possible. Seems like you could have a sequence going to (1/3,1/3) whose image is wildly divergent.

Comment: @MikeMiller We are given a topology coming from a metric on the domain and codomain. So if $(s_n)_n$ has a limit when included in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then this means it is a Cauchy sequence in the domain of $f$. Then, so is $(f(s_n))_n$ in the codomain, by 'epsilon-delta'. So, $(f(s_n)_n$ should indeed have a limit when included in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @polynomial_donut You have no epsilon delta statement about the extension. You've made no assumption about *its* continuity! To be not  clear, consider the map $S^1 \setminus \{-1\} \to (0,2\pi)$ given by taking a logarithm. This does not have an extension to a map $S^1 \to [0,2\pi]$. The only way you can extend continuous maps on metric spaces to their completions is by *assuming* (not necessarily convergent in your incomplete space) Cauchy sequences are sent to Cauchy sequences. This is usually false.

Comment: @MikeMiller Sure, I also haven't stated I had a bullet proof proof ;) Niels Diepeveen's comment above refers to a paper that seems to speak in favor of the possibility of such an extension, though, or maybe I completely misunderstood it  at my first glance. Thanks for the example, by the way!

Comment: @polynomial_donut The paper gives an example of such a homeomorphism that does extend; it certainly doesn't imply all do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a theorem due to Brouwer (1913) that for any two dense countable subsets $A, B\subset R^n$, there is a homeomorphism $R^n\to R^n$ sending $A$ to $B$ bijectively. See also "General Topology" by Engelking (he has this as an exercise 4.5.2, with a detailed hint). If I remember it correctly, Hirsch in "Differential Topology" also has this as an exercise where instead of a homeomorphism he asks for a diffeomorphism. Lastly,

M. Morayne, *Measure preserving analytic diffeomorphisms of countable dense sets in $C^n$ and $R^n$*,  Colloq. Math. 52 (1987), no. 1, 93–98.

proves that for any two countable dense subsets $A, B$ in $R^n$, $n\ge 2$, there exists an analytic volume-preserving diffeomorphism of $R^n\to R^n$ sending $A$ to $B$ bijectively.

So, the conclusion is that your spaces are homeomorphic.